# Apache POI - Is there a way to count occurrence of a string in a pivot table?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using version 4.1.2 of Apache Poi and I have this dataset:

```
String[] headers = new String[] { "Company", "Status" };

Object[][] sheetData = {
                {"Company 1", "OK"},
                {"Company 1", "NG"},
                {"Company 2", "NG"},
                {"Company 1", "OK"},
                {"Company 3", "OK"},
                {"Company 1", "NG"},
        };
```

I'm trying to create a pivot table using Apache POI that groups and counts the occurrence of strings from the 2nd column. I've tried:

```
pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.COUNT, 1);
```

But it somehow still counts the occurrences from the first column.

The pivot table I'm trying to create:

[image]

and the pivot table that is being generated:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pivot table you are showing as the one you are trying to create shows the column `1` = `B` (Status) as a column label using a `DataConsolidateFunction` as well as column label used for labeling columns. So one column has two different properties in the pivot table here. That makes it complicated.

The `DataConsolidateFunction` column label is done already using `pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.COUNT, 1)`. This also sets `dataField` setting for the column.

For the column label used for labeling columns `apache poi 4.1.2` provides the method [XSSFPivotTable.addColLabel](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFPivotTable.html#addColLabel-int-). But this method removes the `dataField` setting. So we need set it new using the low level `ooxml-shemas` classes.

And the order of the commands is important here because they  effect the same column. First do `pivotTable.addColumnLabel`and then do `pivotTable.addColLabel`. Else `addColumnLabel` will set `dataField` setting but will remove `axis="axisCol"` setting from that column. But because of the two different properties in the pivot table both settings are needed for that column.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.SpreadsheetVersion;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.AreaReference;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataConsolidateFunction;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

class CreatePivotTable {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String[] headers = new String[] { "Company", "Status" };
  Object[][] sheetData = {
   {"Company 1", "OK"},
   {"Company 1", "NG"},
   {"Company 2", "NG"},
   {"Company 1", "OK"},
   {"Company 3", "OK"},
   {"Company 1", "NG"},
  };

  try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("./ExcelResult.xlsx") ) {

   XSSFSheet dataSheet = workbook.createSheet("Data");
   XSSFRow row;
   XSSFCell cell;
   int r = 0;
   row = dataSheet.createRow(r++);
   int c = 0;
   for (String header : headers) {
    cell = row.createCell(c++);
    cell.setCellValue(header);
   }
   for (Object[] dataRow : sheetData) {
    row = dataSheet.createRow(r++);
    c = 0;
    for (Object value : dataRow) {
     cell = row.createCell(c++);
     if (value instanceof String) {
      cell.setCellValue((String)value);
     } //else if...
    }
   } 

   XSSFSheet pivotSheet = workbook.createSheet("Pivot");

   AreaReference areaReference = new AreaReference(
    new CellReference(0, 0),
    new CellReference(sheetData.length, headers.length-1),
    SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);

   XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = pivotSheet.createPivotTable(areaReference, new CellReference("A4"), dataSheet);

   pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
   pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.COUNT, 1);

   pivotTable.addColLabel(1);
   //Method addColLabel removes the dataField setting. So we need set it new.
   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(1)
    .setDataField(true);

   workbook.write(fileout);

  }

 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the sample. It worked!